# mapping graduated symbols in arcpy for data with changing max value

Tags: mapping, range, legend, arcpy

I have a pyscript that I am working on and running into issues with the legend.

The goal of the script is to take a csv file with two columns (country, value) that I am joining to a world map based on country name. Once they are joined I turn it into a lyr file and then start to work on the mapping aspects of it.

I want to change the field being mapped to 'value' and then change the mapping to graduated symbols with 5 breaks (at 5,20,50,75,100 % of the max value in the map). The problem being that depending on what layer file is being used the max value changes. I have spent a lot of time searching for how to do this and have still come up short, there are probably some unnecessary bits to my code as well as I am now to python.

**How can I get it to map based on graduated symbol based on 5 percent breaks with a changing max value?**

Some of the code I have been working on below,

```
import os, sys, string, arcpy, arcpy.mapping, glob, arcgisscripting,time 
from arcpy import env
```

call blank mxd file, set feature layer, Declare variables

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(workspace/blank_4.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
```

'newname' is the layer file being used

```
sourceLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(newname)
```

Convert feature classes to layer objects

```
outLayer = str(newname)
curmap = workspace + filename + ".shp"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(curmap, outLayer)
```

Save layer objects to layer files

```
LayerFile = str(outLayer) + ".lyr"
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(outLayer, LayerFile)
```

Define variable for the new layer using LayerFile object

```
newlayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(LayerFile)
```

Adds the new layer to top of TOC in the mxd doc map document

```
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, newlayer, "TOP")
```

change the mapping field from country name to fert value

```
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, newlayer, df)[0]
symbols = arcpy.mapping.Layer(C:\workspace\graduated_symbol2.lyr")
```

graduated symbols is a blank layer file where I created a legend with 5 breaks (5,20,50,75,100 %) but the range was created based on a max value of 22,000 and now when I run a file with a max value of 35,000 anything above 22,000 becomes blank.

**How can I get it to purely work on % breaks, and have the 0/max range of the respective csv file be used??????**

Update new layer with sybmology from the source layer

```
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(lyr,symbols) 
arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, lyr, symbols, True)
```

change symbology, colors, and breaks

```
if lyr.symbologyType == "GRADUATED_COLORS":
lyr.symbology.valueField = "value"
print lyr.symbology.numClasses #
```

Then I output this to a pdf, but that part is working.

Thanks!

Comment: Not a complete answer, but maybe use Python's csv module to read the CSV to get your max value, then transfer this value over as a parameter to your arcpy.mapping code?

Comment: Just in case you are not aware of it there is a [gis.se] Stack Exchange with MANY ArcPy questions already answered on it.